# DJango - __in database query

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have the following data structure: **FruitObject** with fields **FruitType** and **FruitColor**. On the other hand I have **FruitOffer** (which is input by user). It has same fields as **FruitObject** and is being input by user (some kind of demand-support pairing system; we input FruitObjects and user input FruitOffers; the task is to pair them and see what a user has to offer us - to select only those FruitObjects that are equal to FruitOffers for specific user).

So logically I've used **__in** selection to get needed data:

```
select = FruitObject.objects.filter(FruitType__in=FruitOffer.objects.filter(user=request.user).values("FruitType"))
```

Now comes the hard part for me - I need to add FruitColor to the select and get many-to-many select that fulfills both conditions (for each fruitObject get offerObject that is **BOTH** of TYPE and COLOR)

```
select = FruitObject.objects.filter(FruitType__in=FruitOffer.objects.filter(user=request.user).values("FruitType"), FruitColor__in=FruitOffer.objects.filter(user=request.user).values("FruitColor"))
```

But comma is operating more like OR in this case and returns me all values that are of specific Type or of specific Color.

How do add **AND** condition to __in select? If i'd like to add more conditions (like price or taste), will it be done in same way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hard way.

```
FruitObject.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(FruitColor=color, FruitType=type) for (color, type) in FruitOffer.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('FruitColor', 'FruitType'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Q
fruit_type = FruitOffer.objects.filter(user=request.user).values("FruitType")
fruit_color= FruitOffer.objects.filter(user=request.user).values("FruitColor")

select = FruitObject.objects.filter( Q(FruitType__in=fruit_type)) & Q(FruitColor__in=fruit_color) )
```

Comment: This does a cross match, not an inner match; if there exists `A×1` and `B×2`, this will also match `A×2` and `B×1`.

Comment: Yes, Ignacio is right, it is a cross match and returns all values that are equal to A, B, 1 or 2. Not values that are equal to A1 and B2

Answer (score 0):

Use **Q** objects for lookups https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects